# Is this considered a bad practice in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, events

I'm not really good at English and i mainly develop in java, i was trying to create an external evenlistener for a clickevent, but i keep getting the feeling that it is wrong.

Here is my example:
the form..

```
public partial class MainFrame : System.Windows.Forms.Form
{
    private System.ComponentModel.Container components = null;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button startButton;

    public MainFrame()
    {
        initGUI();
    }

    private void initGUI()
    {
        this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();

        this.Text = "CustomGUI";

        ShowIcon = false;

        this.startButton = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        startButton.Text = "Start";
        startButton.SetBounds(0, 0, 100, 25);

        this.Controls.Add(this.startButton);

        MainEventListener listen = new MainEventListener();
        startButton.Click += listen.startClicked;

    }


}
```

Next: the listener..

```
class MainEventListener
{

    public void startClicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }


}
```

Finally: the main method..

```
 class ApplicationStarter
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MainFrame frame = new MainFrame();
        System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(frame);
    }
}
```

I keep getting the feeling I'm doing it in the wrong way.

Answer (score 2):

1. You don't have to write all this yourself. Visual Studio provides a template and a Designer to manage all the Form-Initialization and configuration code. (InitGUI => InitializeComponent in a partial class).
2. In C# you don't have to create a Listener class. Just use events.

Comment: And that does not add useless code like netbeans?

Comment: I don't know netbeans but give it a try. Not much fat there.

Comment: It adds plenty of extra code, but it's hidden away in the designer file. It hides away the component positioning and the event wiring. You just need to say "onClick" do "xyz" in the event setup in visual studio.  It'll then create an event handler for you in code that you can rename if you want

Comment: Also, assuming this is your main form(going by the class name here), by default your application will exit when the form is closed.